# How to see correspondence between G-covers and homomorphisms

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

I found this paper on van Kampen's theorem (https://www3.nd.edu/~andyp/notes/SeifertVanKampen.pdf), and I was wondering how to prove Lemma 1:

*Let Z be a reasonable nonempty path-connected space, let G be a
group, and let p ∈ Z. Then there is a natural bijection*

*{homomorphisms π_1(Z, p) → G} ↔ {based regular G-covers (Y, q) → (Z, p)}.*

Why is this true? This is certainly not immediately clear to me. Also, how does the version of van Kampen's theorem in this paper relate to the version using amalgamated free products?

Note that I'm only self-taught via Hatcher's book, so I apologize if this is obvious.

Comment: If the maps were required to be surjective I would say to look at the kernel of these maps, which give you exactly what you want via the cover-subgroup correspondence. If the maps aren’t surjective though, you don’t get $G$-covers, but $\operatorname{im}(\pi_1 \to G)$-covers...

Comment: I don't think they are required to be surjective. In fact, from what little I can find elsewhere, the surjective maps correspond to path-connected G-covers. My main impediment is constructing the maps between Hom($\pi_1(Z,p),G$) and the regular G-covers. Is there any intuition behind this?

Comment: Ah, I see. The author mentions this right after the statement of the lemma. So, in the connected cover case, can you see the correspondence?

Comment: Why should the homomorphisms between the fundamental group and the deck transformations have anything to do with the cover itself? I know I’m missing something fundamental, but I don’t know where to look.

Comment: [Let's discuss this in chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics)

Comment: I feel the question asked is more easily answered in terms of the algebraic model of coverings spaces using covering morphisms of groupoids. See 10.6.4 of my book Topology and Groupoids, available as pdf from my web site, for a discussion of regular covering morphisms.

Comment: Is there a way to look at this without using category theory?

Comment: Can someone explain the disconnected cover/non-surjective homomorphism case? I understand the correspondence in the case that the homomorphisms are surjective, but I don't see how I can get a cover with deck transform group $G$ out of a quotient of $\pi_1(Z,p)$ that is only contained in $G$. This case is important for the universal property that the author is trying to prove...