# What is a "based regular G-cover"

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, covering-spaces

This is a simple question, but I can't seem to find the definition in the topology books I have lying around: What is a "based regular $G$-cover", where $G$ is a group?

I am trying to understand the same Lemma referred to in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3184414/how-to-see-correspondence-between-g-covers-and-homomorphisms) (Lemma 1 of [these notes](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eandyp/notes/SeifertVanKampen.pdf)), but I can't follow the discussion there due to not knowing the definition!

Comment: That all makes sense, thanks! I'll have to go back to Hatcher and try to piece together the results there to get to the Lemma used in that note since I don't see that Lemma explicitly anywhere

Answer (score 1):

A regular $G$-cover is a regular or normal or Galois cover (ie one such that the deck group acts transitively on each fiber) with deck group $G$. A based or pointed topological space is a topological space $X$ with a choice of basepoint $x \in X$. So a based regular $G$-cover is a regular cover with deck group $G$ and a chosen basepoint, and if the target of the covering map is already based or pointed then the basepoint of the cover should be in its preimage so that the covering map is based or pointed.